# Create a custom ListActivity adapter with two TextViews to handle two ArrayList<String> objects

Tags: android, adapter

I have two `ArrayLists` which I have populated from the `Contacts` `Content Provider`:

```
public class AddBuddiesActivity extends ListActivity 
{
  public ArrayList<String> allNames;
  public ArrayList<String> allNumbers;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    // initialize and populate these lists
    ...
```

I set up an xml layout to prepare the display of the two `lists`.

**group_addbuddies.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/buddy_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/buddy_number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now I would like to setup the `adapter` for the `ListActivity` so I can popular the two lists inside the rows of two `text views`

```
// inside onCreate()
// somehow create an adapter
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

How do I go about creating a `custom list adapter` that will inflate `buddy_name` with `ArrayList<String> allNames` and `buddy_number` with `ArrayList<String> allNumbers`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should merge your two arrays into one array. It will save you a lot of troubles and will fit easier with the framework. Just create a simple class to hold two Strings (or use Pair object, but it's far less future-proof, wouldn't recommend).

Create a typed array adapter based on that custom data class, override getView and put each string in the corresponding TextView and you're good to go.

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyData>{

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        MyData item = getItem(position);

        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.buddy_name)).setText(item.getName());
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.buddy_number)).setText(item.getNumber());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a very elegant way to do it.  I have completed my task in even less lines of code than I ever attempted.  Beautiful!  I'll post my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Set your ListAdapter like this

```
setListAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), allNames, allNumbers));
```

and here is the Adapter class

**CustomListAdapter.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Context mContext;
    public ArrayList<String> allNames;
    public ArrayList<String> allNumbers;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> allNames,
            ArrayList<String> allNumbers) {
        super(mContext, R.layout.group_addbuddies, allNames);
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.allNames = allNames;
        this.allNumbers = allNumbers;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder mHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_addbuddies, parent, false);
            mHolder = new ViewHolder();
            mHolder.buddy_name = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.buddy_name);
            mHolder.buddy_number = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.buddy_number);
            convertView.setTag(mHolder);
        } else {
            mHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        mHolder.buddy_name.setText(allNames.get(position));
        mHolder.buddy_number.setText(allNumbers.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView buddy_name;
        private TextView buddy_number;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you answering my question as posed.  While I accepted the other answer because it was more elegant and less lines of code, I upvoted yours because it is perfect for learning purposes.

Comment: @mindandsky : Yes I appreciate your concern but just want to give you an advice when making a adapter you should reuse the view and use holders to improve performance. Read on this http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2013/03/12/recycling-views-listview when you use a adapter for a listview next time. The performance improvement is nearly double